# Undefined Reference to boost

Tags: ros, makefile, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I've been getting this error lately every time I compile my ethzasl_sensor_fusion.

The error I received is below:

### Linking CXX executable ../bin/pose_sensor
CMakeFiles/pose_sensor.dir/src/main.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0': /usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to` boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()' /usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to` boost::system::system_category()'
CMakeFiles/pose_sensor.dir/src/pose_sensor.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0': /usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to` boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()' /usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to` boost::system::system_category()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../bin/pose_sensor] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/fyp4211/ROS_Pack/ethzasl_sensor_fusion/ssf_updates/build' make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/pose_sensor.dir/all] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/fyp4211/ROS_Pack/ethzasl_sensor_fusion/ssf_updates/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/fyp4211/ROS_Pack/ethzasl_sensor_fusion/ssf_updates/build'

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package ssf_updates written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/fyp4211/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130401-152352/ssf_updates/build_output.log

The cmake file is shown below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
#set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
#gencfg()
rosbuild_genmsg()

add_definitions (-Wall)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

# get eigen
find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS})

rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
rosbuild_add_executable(pose_sensor src/main.cpp src/pose_sensor.cpp)
rosbuild_link_boost(pose_sensor filesystem system)
set_property(TARGET pose_sensor PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS POSE_MEAS)
rosbuild_add_compile_flags(pose_sensor "-O3")
target_link_libraries(pose_sensor ssf_core)

rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
rosbuild_add_executable(position_sensor src/main.cpp src/position_sensor.cpp)
rosbuild_link_boost(position_sensor filesystem system)
set_property(TARGET position_sensor PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS POSITION_MEAS)
rosbuild_add_compile_flags(position_sensor "-O3")
target_link_libraries(position_sensor ssf_core)
```

Can you guys help me out with this problem.
Thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59672/undefined-reference-to-boost/) by [ROS_NOOB_CYBORG](https://answers.ros.org/users/3275/ros_noob_cyborg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add following line to your cmake

```
rosbuild_link_boost(pose_sensor system)
```

sorry I deleted my previous answer+ your comment while I was going to edit it.

---

Originally posted by [hiranya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3446/hiranya/) with karma: 104 on 2013-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROS_NOOB_CYBORG](https://answers.ros.org/users/3275/ros_noob_cyborg/) on 2013-04-02**:
Yeah..So what I did is put that line after rosbuild_add_executable(pose_sensor src/main.cpp src/pose_sensor.cpp). And..the results is the same. Any other idea..Thanks!

**Comment by [hiranya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3446/hiranya/) on 2013-04-02**:
you tried target_link_libraries (pose_sensor boost_system) as well, may be  boost should install sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev

**Comment by [ROS_NOOB_CYBORG](https://answers.ros.org/users/3275/ros_noob_cyborg/) on 2013-04-03**:
I put my target_link_libraries (pose_sensor boost_system) after my target_link_libraries(pose_sensor ssf_core) and for apt-get install libboost-all-dev the results I get is
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded. Still get error haha..

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-05-06**:
I'd remove the multiple calls to add_boost_directories, and play with the ordering of commands.